# How to evaluate trigonometric function sine?

Tags: trigonometry

$$g = 357.528˚ + 0.9856008˚ n$$
$$\lambda = L + 1.915˚ \sin g + 0.020˚ \sin(2g)$$

My calculator is the Python Interpreter.
How can I calculate this? What will the resulting lambda be? Degrees? Ratio? Angle?

Comment: Is not this already in english? Can you choose a more significant title?

Comment: I changed the title.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? A formula can't be solved..

Comment: I guess you are asking the precedence order of $addition$, $multiplication$ and $trigonometric~function~evaluation$.

Comment: I have the variables. I just don't know how to enter them into my calculator. I'm sorry. I really need to understand this.

Comment: The order ( precedence) of operations is as follows: First evaluate the sines, then multiply by the coefficients, and then do the summation.

Comment: What calculator do you have? If you have a graphing calculator, you can just type in the formula as above. If not, you have to follow Q-rious' instructions.

Comment: I'm using the python interpreter @Rainier van Es.

Comment: @Q-rious When you say evaluate the sines, do you mean multiply 1.915 degrees by sine?

Comment: I just included g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate this expression in the python interpreter, as the comments state you're using.

If you're using radians do this:

```
>>> import math
>>> L = <type value of L here>
>>> g = <type value of g here>
>>> L + 1.915 * math.sin(g) + 0.02 * math.sin(2*g)
```

If you're using degress do this:

```
>>> import math
>>> L = <type value of L here>
>>> g = math.radians(<type value of g here>)
>>> L + 1.915 * math.sin(g) + 0.02 * math.sin(2*g)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the sine values be converted into degrees, since the coefficients are also in degrees? The *math.sin(x)* function gives the angle in radians.

Comment: I thought so. Where I'm held up at is the question of degrees. Do I have to treat 1.915 any different because it is a degree?

Comment: @MansaMusa You should consider adjusting the angle in degree by multiplying $\frac{\pi}{180}$.

Comment: @RainiervanEs You know what I'm talking about! Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, exactly! ;-)

Comment: @RainiervanEs I'm a bit confused by his use of degrees multiplied by sine as the sine function takes an angle and returns a distance, it dosen't return an angle.

Comment: @RainiervanEs If you see what he means, please go ahead and edit my question.

Comment: @Darksonn I think this is what he means, thanks for editing.

Comment: I attempted to edit what you offered so that we can be sure this is correct. I hope I haven't been too troublesome. I appreciate the help and will be sure to return the favor where I can.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, then you are asking something like this:

> $$\lambda=(L+(1.915^{\circ} \times (\sin g)_{\color{#0c0}1})_{\color{#00c}2} + (0.020^\circ  \times (\sin(2g)_{\color{#0c0}1})_{\color{#00c}2}))_{\color{#c00}3}$$

1. First evaluate $\sin$ 's
2. Then $\times$ 's
3. Then $+$

*The subscripts in colored fonts indicate the ordering of the operations (i.e., their respective precedence order).*

Answer (score 0):

Some parenthesis may help : 
$$
\lambda = L + (1.915˚ \sin( g) )+ (0.020˚ \sin(2g))
$$

Now start with the innermost parenthesis, evaluate the expression inside, substitute the result for the parenthesis, and recursively do this until there are no parenthesis left.
You may also want to look at this: [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: I understand basic order of operations. It's the sin and the degrees that are bugging me.